# PHP Formatar tempo contendo letra no valor

Tags: php

Exemplo: 2h53m23s
Gostaria que ficasse assim:02:53:23

Exemplo no meu codigo

```html
<?php 

valor_com_letra = "2h53m23s;

aqui a formatacao 


echo $valor_com_letra; //resultado 02:53:23



;?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Um jeito simples é fazer replace desses valores

Ex

```
str_replace('s','', str_replace(['h','m'], ':', $valor_com_letra));
```

Comment: Perfeito meu amigo obrigado ta !

Comment: So estou com um probleminha srrs  quando vem assim o valor : 58m26s gostaria que ficasse assim 00:58:26

Comment: no caso ele fica assim: 58:26 ai nao entra no sistema entendi

Comment: Você pode fazer um IF verificando a quantidade de caracteres. Se for 5 após o tratamento, você adiciona 00: na frente